# Rally Rest API - Copy rally template to Features

Tags: java, rally

1. Have any sample java code for copy existing rally template to Features .
2. API for accessing template under projects.

Comment: @All.. Any suggestions on my request

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any examples for this, however it's probably important to know if you're referring to EDP templates or QDP templates.

The reason I bring this up is because EDP templates are going to need to be migrated to QDP templates due to deprecation of the EDP style pages.  Check out this community post for more info: https://communities.ca.com/thread/241818626-product-announcement-migrate-rich-text-edp-templates-to-work-item-qdp-templates

The other thing is, there's an app that's been written to help customer migrate their templates: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krmorse/RichTextTemplateViewer/master/deploy/App-uncompressed.html

This app, while not Java, might give you some ideas on working with templates from a code perspective